# Can I send ETH to an Smart Contract address?

Tags: crowdsale, openzeppelin-contracts, sendtransaction

I'm developing an Smart Contract based in the [Openzeppelin's Crowdsale one](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.5.1/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol).
When I test the Crowdsale Smart Contract manually, sending ETH with metamask, the SC returns me the correct amount of tokens.

But when I try to do the same (send ETH to the Smart Contract's address) I always get an error on Metamask before sending the amount.

I have tried with:
**sendTransaction**

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({'to': toaddr, 'from': fromAddress, 'value': bnb_value})
```

(If I change the contract's address with a wallet address, the function sends the ETH correctly to the given wallet address, but not when the address is a contract addres).

**buyTokens function**

```
 ico_contract.methods.buyTokens(fromaddr).estimateGas({
          "value": bnb_value,
          "from": fromAddress
        })
```

I do not know how to continue...

Comment: What is the address you are sending the ETH from (In both cases?) Is it the same or?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and everything was because of not providing gasLimit parameter (and also because of manually testing the contract ended with no tokens). I set the gasLimit param in the request with estimateGas() function and everything worked fine.

```
            let gaslimit;
            web3.eth.estimateGas({
              nonce: web3.utils.toHex(nonce),
              gasPrice: gasPrice,
              value: bnb_value,
              from: fromaddr,
              to: toaddr,
              chainId: web3.utils.toHex(97)
              })
              .then(function(gas) {
                gaslimit = web3.utils.toHex(gas);
              })
              .catch(function(error) {
                console.error(error);
              });
```